# Is Web Farm Framework Supported by Microsoft in 2023?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2019

We have a few dozen **Windows Server 2019** machines running IIS. I just found out about **Web Farm Framework**, which is a thing developed over 10 years ago that makes managing multiple IIS instances easier.

My question is: **Is Web Farm Framework still supported by Microsoft?** The official documentation about it doesn't reference Windows Server 2019, hence my concern that Microsoft has abandoned it and won't support it anymore.

Comment: Web Farm Framework is a dead end product.

Comment: Ok, so what is best practice in 2023 for managing IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from [my own post](https://halfblood.pro/status-of-iis-out-of-band-modules-80a3af57c489),

> They are deprecated for IIS 10 and above.

> However, they remain fully supported on IIS ... 8.x.

> Web Farm Framework users should consider Azure Stack for private cloud usage. If you insist on running a classic web farm for IIS 10, there isn't anything similar offered by Microsoft right now.

Since IIS 8.x is going to reach end of life in just a few months, you can assume Web Farm Framework reaches its end-of-life the same way.

Comment: I suspect that some of this functionality is probably handled by the various CD products (Octopus/Jenkins).